# Different types of Users for a task in a Business Process

Tags: bpel, bpmn

How to assign a task to different types of users. Each user may have different attributes of completion for example time, accuracy and cost. Thus depending upon a matrix I want to design a scheduling mechanism which minimizes the Cost.

How do I define this type (see image) of process using BPMN specification.

[BPMN Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kgco.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case, I would use multiple instances activity (sometimes called multi instanciation in BPMS)

Multiple instances activity executes the same activity several times (a bit like a loop) but in different configurations. By configuration, I mean the user, the job to do, ...
Two kinds of multiple instances activity exists : parallel or sequencial.

In your case, parallel multiple instances would answer the need.

Hope it helps